# Truncate a string if contains a word longer than a certain value

Tags: javascript, string, truncate

I want truncate the string if contains a word that is longer than a certain value. For example, if the string is this one:

> "test fassfsaf longstring 1112faffasfsaffasfssafssssafafsas"

and i want truncate the string if a word have size > 8 then the result must be:

> "test fassfsaf longstri"

Any suggestion?

Comment: try to take substring of length 0-8, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split the string using `split(" ")` will return you an array of words. you can use `filter()` here, accept elements till first word with length>8. to make the string back use `join(" ")` on filter array of words.

```js
var str = "test fassfsaf longstring 1112faffasfsaffasfssafssssafafsas";

str = str.split(" ");
str = str.filter((x, index, arr) => !(x.length > 8 && arr[index-1].length > 8));
str[str.length - 1] = str[str.length - 1].substr(0,8);

console.log(str.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `split()` the string using `" "`.Then recreate the array with map  using `slice(0,8)` condition.And finally, `join()` the string with `" "`

```js
var a="test fassfsaf longstring 1112faffasfsaffasfssafssssafafsas";
var r = a.split(' ').map(i=> i.slice(0,8));

console.log(r.join(" "))
```

Comment: @Ram a.slice(0,8) is not enough because it return "test fas" instead the string that I want

For the solution proposed by prasad I lost the spaces when i rebuilt the string

Comment: @Ram .It's not enough. op ask for  *`if contains a word`* each word.Not with whole string only.